# Change default sticky header logo to 2nd logo

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

With 2 logos (1 for default header, 2nd for sticky header) created in CSS.

In applying the HTML, do I apply 2 header id's or can I somehow implement the 2nd logo within the default header logo div class?

```
<div class="body"> 
    <header id="header" data-plugin-options='{"stickyEnabled": true, "stickyEnableOnBoxed": true, "stickyEnableOnMobile": true, "stickyStartAt": 57, "stickySetTop": "-57px", "stickyChangeLogo": true}'> 
        <div class="header-body"> 
            <div class="header-container container"> 
                <div class="header-row"> 
                    <div class="header-column"> 
                        <div class="header-logo"> 
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img alt="" width="270" height="70" data-sticky-width="270" data-sticky-height="60" data-sticky-top="33" src="img/logo.jpg">
                            </a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

The header is sticky and the logo resizes great. My issue is I want the "Resized Logo" to become my Secondary Logo

Comment: 2 DIFFERENT STYLED but same company logo - Thanks!

Comment: Are you making your header sticky with a scroll function? If yet please post the function.

Comment: <div class="body">
   <header id="header" data-plugin-options='{"stickyEnabled": true, "stickyEnableOnBoxed": true, "stickyEnableOnMobile": true, "stickyStartAt": 57, "stickySetTop": "-57px", "stickyChangeLogo": true}'>
    <div class="header-body">
     <div class="header-container container">
      <div class="header-row">
       <div class="header-column">
        <div class="header-logo">
         <a href="index.html">
          <img alt="" width="270" height="70" data-sticky-width="270" data-sticky-height="60" data-sticky-top="33" src="img/logo.jpg">
    </a>
   /div> </div>

Comment: jeez copy and past didn't work to well on this comment box - sorry

Comment: My header is sticky and the logo resizes great.

Comment: My issue is I want the "Resized Logo" to become my Secondary Logo

Comment: I've edited your question to add the code from your comments and formatted it so that it can be easily read. The more clear you make your question, the more likely you will get an answer.